# Batch: Copy images from the text file to another folder

Tags: powershell

I'm dummy in all of this, and English is not my native language.
Here is question, I have a list of barcodes (or ID's shown in first image), and I have a folder with 4000 images with the a barcode name, a lot of them have two pictures for one barcode(see second image). I need to move or copy images from list, not only one image but all images for one barcode.

[first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJaMd.png)
[image]

[second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSnZQ.png)
[image]

Example: `2000000079127` in the list
need to move/copy: `2000000079127.jpg`, `2000000079127_2.jpg`, `2000000079127_3.jpg`, `2000000079127_4.jpg` image from one folder to another.

Please help me with it, can`t find solution.

I don`t know how to code.

Comment: Please (also) post your code, data, error messages as ([properly formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)) _text_, [not (just) as _images_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/45375). Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Please read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please post the code you are trying to make work. SO is not a free, bespoke script writing service.

Comment: Have you tried to search for examples? [Search PowerShell Copy Files From List](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5BPowerShell%5D+copy+files+from+a+list)